# I asked my friend what had happened

Tags: vocabulary

> I need to **ask** you a question. = (less commonly) I need to **ask** a question **of** you.
>   (Merriam-Webster’s Learner’s, [ask #1](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/ask))
>
> You cannot say ‘*ask to somebody*’: *I asked to my friend what had happened. 
>   (OALD, [ask #1](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/ask_1))

When you ask questions, ‘*ask to somebody*’ cannot be used, says OALD. What about the next example? It’s the pattern of Merriam-Webster’s, but whose bracket ‘*less commonly*’ makes me to wonder if this sentence can be used.

> [next example] I **asked** what had happened **of** my friend.

Comment: The "of" form is used much more commonly with "favor". *I need to ask a favor of you.*  *I need to ask you a favor.*

Comment: And by the above comment, I mean "ask a favor of you" is more common than "ask a question of you".

Comment: The preposition ***of*** in these contexts is usually dated/archaic/formal/literary. Perhaps for that reason you still encounter it in formal request contexts like [*"I need to ask a favour of you"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22need+to+ask+a+favour+of+you%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) (129 hits in Google Books). But even there most native speakers would say [*"I need to ask you a favour"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22need+to+ask+you+a+favour%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) (1540 hits). In short, it's probably best forgotten (or never learned! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's ridiculous to tell someone to never learn a phrase that one commonly encounters in contemporary English, namely *I need to ask a favor of you.* It is also not the case that this phrase is always formal, and it is certainly not dated.

Comment: @Carsmack: the construction is rare enough to make me think of one specific song immediately, though: [All I ask of you](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCoQtwIwAg&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Duxs7qevmy50&ei=PPJJVJfRBtjuaNqGgZAH&usg=AFQjCNH8xgHmdqDkNuke2384t8qRtYyKMA&sig2=hpnrelc-WTIWRW1fikiVFQ&bvm=bv.77880786,d.d2s)

Comment: @Carsmack: Scrolling to the *second* page of the 129 Google Books results I linked to above, it turns out there are actually only 19 instances of *"I need to ask a favour of you"*. In fact, they're all from the past decade, but it's obvious from the snippet views that several are deliberately intended to reflect antiquated usages in fictional narratives. Whatever - I think it's effectively just a "frozen form". Nobody says to their kid today *"Go and sit on Santa's knee, and he'll ask **of** you what you want for Christmas"*.

Comment: @oerkelens: I didn't know that song, but in most real-world contexts today (particularly if the speaker wasn't *trying* to sound "formal") I think it would probably come out as *"All I ask **from** you [is the shirt off your back, or whatever]"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: It's from the Phantom of the Opera, a musical that is based in the Paris Opera around the turn of the 20th century. Both _archaic_ and _formal_ are probably appropriate for the occasion, thus illustrating your argument :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to use the "of" form, you would need to reference the person being asked:

**I asked of him what had become of my friend.**

But this would be something you might have heard in Shakespeare's day.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

It means the same thing as

> I asked my friend what happened.

The form "I asked *of* my friend what happened" is grammatically correct, but it is simply archaic, and as such not often used anymore. The easier option, without preposition, is also the one you will see most often used, so (for once?) the easy option is the best one.

---

Some extra background, just informational, about the specific sentence:

*Because* it is not commonly used, it may actually cause confusion, because people may think you mean to say:

> I asked what happened **to** my friend.

I actually read the sentence in you question initially like that, "correcting" the preposition in my head, because I wrongly assumed you used the wrong preposition.

So you might give people the feeling you mean something else than what you say, even though what you say is grammatically correct. Since communication aims at getting the right message across, I think it is better to use *I asked my friend* to avoid sounding archaic, and possibly, confusion.

Comment: I don't agree. I think no native speaker would make the misunderstanding you suggest, and we *don't* adjust our syntax to address potential difficulties for non-native speakers. We just wouldn't normally use the ***of*** form because it's dated/formal, as per my comment to the question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I have been "corrected" at least twice by native speakers who told me I should use "to" in that (kind of) sentence. Maybe they were quite special...

Comment: Hmm - "special" as in "special needs student", perhaps. No normal native speaker ever *asks something **to** someone*. It just so happens that you might *ask someone* what happened ***to** someone else* (or what happened ***in** some place*, or ***at** some time*). But these are not remotely confusing or ambiguous preposition usages (for native speakers! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I never stated a native speaker would say that. I said that a native speaker might think I mean _to_ as in _what happened to my friend_ if I say "I asked what happened of my friend". The confusion stems from the non-native using an archaic construction in a sentence that with another preposition would be completely idiomatic, leading the native speaker to the assumption that the learner made a mistake. Also native speakers of normal mental capacity do sometimes display an emphatic will to try and help learners.

Comment: oic. Well, I've made a "non-edit" to your answer so I could retract the downvote, but I have to point out that nowhere in your answer does it mention that the reason we don't usually use ***of*** there is because in most contexts it's dated/archaic. I really don't think potential ambiguity and/or non-native speaker errors are particularly relevant to current idiomatic usage for native speakers.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: ah, I was puzzled about the edit. You do have a point, I will add that to my answer :)

Comment: I only *cancelled* the downvote on the basis of our comments here, but seeing the revised answer text I'm now quite happy to *reverse* it into an upvote. It's not that I think your other points aren't valid and worth making - I just think for learners in particular it's important we make it clear when some "technically valid" usage has largely fallen into disuse. At least *some* learners will (wisely, imho) decide they don't want to waste brain cells understanding or remembering a usage they're unlikely to encounter often in modern text/speech, or need to generate themselves.